# Testing JDBC queries in JUnit

Tags: java, testing, jdbc, junit

I'm just wondering, what is the best way to test JDBC-related methods? Such as adding users, banning users, etc.

(Using JUnit)

Should I set all my void methods to booleans and have them return true if they've worked, false if they didn't, and assert those values accordingly in my JUnit tests?

This is just a general question to find the best practices.

Thank you!

Comment: Generally what I advise is that this is the province of an integration test. Use an in-memory database such as H2 in place of your regular database and assert that after calling your DAO methods that the tables contain the expected rows.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I personally find an awesome tool for this is [Mockito](https://code.google.com/p/mockito/).  You can mock what a JDBC return would give you so you can say given a specific query and parameter, you'd get a specific value back.

You should not have to modify your code to make it work with unit tests, it should work in both production and test exactly the same way.

You could also consider using an in memory database such as Derby and loading values at the start of your test phase so you know the values that exist in it.  Mocking would probably be faster though in terms of execution time.

Comment: Okay I will try Mockito out thanks!

Comment: If you do this, you will NOT be testing your database code - you'll be testing all those things which depend on your Database code, but not the actual DB code itself. Is that what you want to do?

Answer (score 2):

When I write tests like this I attach to the actual database that I will be running against ( rather than an in-memory database ). Much of my code uses stored procedures or other database specific functionality that isn't necessarily supported by Derby etc.

Whether these are unit or integration tests, I don't know. But they are **important**, so I prefer to get them built in to the Continuous Integration cycle.

If you do use a persistent database then you do have a couple of extra things to worry about. You need to know the state of the data before your tests run, and you should do everything you can to put it back in to the known state as each test runs. If you don't do this your tests will not be independent of each other and you will start to find tests later in the suite start to fail due to failures in earlier tests.

Answer (score 1):

Accessing the database in a unit test is generally not a good idea. I think it would better to mock the database connection and check if the correct queries are called. Of cause that doesn't include the case that the database changed and the queries don't work any more, but that normally happens very rarely.

Answer (score 1):

I think very simple CRUD methods doesn't require to be tested through unit test. Just run the method and then check the table.
Most more complex test will be cover basic CRUD operations.

However, I have already read code where Create/Find operation is tested both in one method like an integration test. The result of find is then compare to the creation request.

EDIT : You can also look at [DB Unit](http://dbunit.sourceforge.net/)